# How to check length of variable with property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have an variable, lets call it `myNiceVar`, I need to check `myNiceVar` value & length, `myNiceVar` variable is just undefined, which for JavaScript compiler this means the variable is defined but does not have any value yet

```js
var myNiceVar;

if(myNiceVar.length){
  console.log("I have value!"); 
}else{
   console.log("I am empty"); 
}
```

Now JavaScript returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How to check something like that and do not getting any error

Comment: Try this: `if(myNiceVar && myNiceVar.length)`.

Comment: @redneb Thanks my Russian friend, that solved my problem

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you think I'm Russian? Does my username mean something in Russian?

Comment: @redneb I am not sure how does he say you are Russian! But now I checked your profile, you have Github account and you are just following one person, and that user is from Moscow! Hmmm! Maybe he said that from your Github! Or maybe you answered questions which are related to Russian language or etc in Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You could check for `typeof` equals `'object'` and if `length` is a key.

Do not forget to check for `null` first, because `null` is an object without properties.

```js
var myNiceVar;

if (myNiceVar !== null && typeof myNiceVar === 'object' && 'length' in myNiceVar) {
    console.log("I have value!");
} else {
    console.log("I am empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var myNiceVar;

if (myNiceVar !== null && typeof myNiceVar === 'object' && 'length' in myNiceVar) {
    console.log("I have value!");
} else {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

An item of type `undefined` (and it is a type) has no `length` property - only items of type string and array do. Therefore, as @redneb notes, extend your condition to check for a non-falsy value before checking length.

```
if (myVar && myVar.length) { ... }
```